# Cordova plugin development

Tags: android, cordova-plugins

I am new to plugin development. I want to build a simple plugin for Apache cordova, that will show a toggle button which will on off the data communication on an android device. I have built it a bit. I wrote the native Java code for data communication on off task but its not working.

Comment: The old hacks to disable mobile data are broken in recent versions.  Please post your code.

Comment: I am having problem posting code on stack overflow how to edit it?